# Special characters in method name in request header

Tags: apache, web, webserver

I am facing one weird issue on my Web server. In my web server access log I found some request header having methods names with special characters in it.
Following is snap from my logs:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:14 +0400] "GET /" 200 44
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:14 +0400] "G\xddET /XYZ/entityIndex.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 6138
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:14 +0400] "\x9fG\xfaET /XYZ/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 501 1124
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:14 +0400] "G@ET /XYZ/css/XYZstyles.css HTTP/1.1" 501 1118
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:14 +0400] "G\xd9ET /XYZ/img/logo-mom.png HTTP/1.1" 501 1120
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:14 +0400] "G\xefET /XYZ/jquery/api/jquery-2.1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 501 1120
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:14 +0400] "G\x0fET /XYZ/jquery/api/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js HTTP/1.1" 501 1118
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:14 +0400] "G\x92ET /XYZ/js/XYZcommon.js HTTP/1.1" 501 1120
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:16 +0400] "POST /XYZ/doXYZLogin.action HTTP/1.1" 302 -
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:17 +0400] "GET /" 200 44
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:17 +0400] "GET /XYZ/XYZIndexPage HTTP/1.1" 200 5772
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:19 +0400] "GET /" 200 44
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:21 +0400] "G\xc8ET /XYZ/jquery/validation/jquery.validate.js HTTP/1.1" 501 1120
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:21 +0400] "G\xd1ET /XYZ/img/XYZ-currency.png HTTP/1.1" 501 1120
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:21 +0400] "G\x1bET /XYZ/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 501 1118
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Jul/2016:10:05:22 +0400] "GET /" 200 44
```

You can see some of the request having invalid GET(e.g G\xddET) method. Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was causing because of CipherSuite selected by web-server to communicate with browser. With following change in configuration issue is resolved now:

```
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!AES128-SHA
```